# UISearchBar change height with animateViewDuration

Tags: ios, animation, frame, uisearchbar

I'm trying to change `UISearchBar's` height ( from 44 ——> 0 ) in the view with `animateWithDuration`,but when I doing this, the `textView` In the searchBar will move out.
And because I'm new here,I can't post an image :(

and here is my code:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
self.searchBar = searchBar;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
}];
```

But I do not find this problem when I change height from 0——>44 like this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
}];
```

anybody help me!why this happened and how to deal with it.Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does "the `textView` in the searchBar will move out" mean?

Comment: thie picture showed the problem :https://github.com/wangmchn/AmazingPageView/blob/master/AmazingPageView/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202015-04-30%2022.45.04.png

Comment: Just like this.half of it disappeared.